# How to select k nodes in a fully connected graph with max separation between any pair of nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Supposing I have a fully connected graph of `N` nodes, and I know the weight between any two pairs of nodes. How do I select `k` nodes such that I maximize the minimum distance between any pair of nodes?

I mapped this problem as a more general case of the one I actually want to solve, which I've dubbed the *cheating students problem* (I don't know if it has an actual name).

---

### **Cheating Students problem**:

Given an `N.M` matrix, how to select `k` cells with maximum distance between any pair of cells? You could assume the matrix is a classroom where `k` cheating students are giving a test. No pair of students should be close to each other, and thus we want to maximize the minimum distance between any pair.

Answer (score 1):

Your generalized graph problem appears to be very closely related to the maximum independent set problem described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29, which is NP-complete. I can find a maximum independent set by running a binary chop to find the largest k for which an algorithm solving your graph problem returns a minimum distance greater than 1. Since finding a maximum independent set is hard, I think your generalized problem is hard.

I don't see an easy way to solve the matrix problem, either, but the related problem of packing circles as efficiently as possible on a 2-d surface of infinite size has been solved, and the answer is what is called a hexagonal packing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) which confusingly is based on a triangular tiling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_tiling - "The vertices of the triangular tiling are the centers of the densest possible circle packing").

So for finite matrices and numbers of students it is possible that arranging the students in widely separated rows, with the rows staggered so that each student is centered between the pair of students nearest them in the row in front of them and behind them, is not too far from optimal - or at least a good place from which to start some sort of hill-climbing attempt.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how Circle Packing may be related to Cheating Students? It seems to me like they are opposite problems; in Circle Packing you want minimum separation, and in Cheating Students you want maximum  separation.

Comment: In circle packing the circles must not overlap. This means that each circle centre is at least the circle diameter away from every other circle centre. So for a very very large matrix the circle packing problem may provide you with a good solution for fitting in k students so that they are all at least one circle diameter away from each other. Whether it is any good for small matrices and values of k that don't happen to arise naturally from nice circle packings is another matter.

Comment: Okay so you're proposing mapping it to the Circle Packing problem by (starting with a high value of the diameter and then (continuously decreasing the diameter until (a valid packing is found with the current diameter))) ?

Comment: I think the hexagonal packing gives you a small number of arrangements where each student is 1, 2, 4, 6, ... cells away from the student to their right. For very large matrices, or matrices that fit exactly onto the pattern, this packing is then the best possible arrangement. If your problem fits into one of these cases great! If not, perhaps you can map it onto the circle packing problem as you suggest and find some code to solve that problem, but perhaps because you have matrices with desks only at exact integer co-ordinates that this will only give you some sort of approximation.